# Laravel http response after successful creation

Tags: php, laravel, testing

After making a POST request to create a new resource, it's common to redirect the browser to a URL for viewing the created resource. Laravel handles this by returning redirect($location) from the controller action.

This is all well and good, except that it makes testing a little bit awkward. It would be great to be able to test these responses with something like:

```
$this->post(...)->assertSuccessful();
```

But that specifically tests for an HTTP status code between 200 and 299. Instead, it seems you need to use:

```
$this->post(...)->assertRedirect($location);
```

There isn't really a problem with that, but it's not ideal, since it's really testing two different things: that the POST request was successful and that the response redirected the user to the created resource.

Is there a better way to handle this? I thought about using a 201 response with a Location header, but browsers don't seem to follow those.

Comment: A test should be as specific as possible because it provides more confidence and makes your test suite less fragile. If you don't care about the response from a HTTP endpoint during testing: don't test it, if you do care about the response then test it meets as specific as possible expectations. If your endpoint is expected to redirect on success: test that it redirects. If you are just testing that the endpoint inserts a record into a database, test that it inserts a record into the database, don't also have a fuzzy test against the response that it is successful just for the sake of it.

Comment: Thanks @sam. That's what I'm doing now, and it works fine, but I'd like to be able to use (and test for) semantically meaningful HTTP status codes as well. Part of the benefit of that is that the same controller actions can easily support browser or API requests.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with laravel 5.5 you can set followingRedirects in the tests:

```
$this->followingRedirects()->post(...)->assertSuccessful();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem since a failed form submission redirects to a GET request on the form page (with errors in the session), which will return a 200 status.

Comment: Then you should use assertSee instead of assertSuccessful